# What's up with Snitchler, the giant treasure goblin?

Tags: diablo-iii

I had gotten a bounty to kill Snitchler in Act 3. When I got to him, I found out that he is actually a HUGE treasure goblin. He acts very much like a normal goblin. You engage him and he picks up his bag and starts running while occasionally dropping gold or loot. I figured he must do something special because he's so giant and his name is in purple (marking him as a unique enemy). As far as I could tell, nothing happened. The loot he dropped wasn't even that great. Is there something I missed? Is there a chance for him to do something different or give a unique item? Is there an achievement? Basically, Is there anything special about him?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's absolutely nothing special about him. Except for the fact that he shouldn't open a portal and escape

Comment: Disclaimer: I do not condone violence against special people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the introduction of the bounty system came a way to be aware of most of the rare spawns in a game. For example, this also includes places like the Caverns of Frost in Act III where people farm for one of the components of the Staff Of Herding.

Prior to the expansion, these rare spawns would have to manually be sought out. Snitchler is one of these such rare spawns. However, Snitchler is not that rare because there are no associated achievements to Snitchler. I killed him last night, it took me 23 new games to get the bounty, and I got no achievement. When examining the list of rare spawn enemies to kill to complete Snitchler was not in the list.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know he is just a "regular" unique monster, and shares the same properties as the other ones. Stronger, bigger, sexier, but not really richer. Being a goblin or not doesn't seem to give more loot. :(